# How to get all items ordered into a text file from an EXCEL sheet using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, file

I have a block of data (below) in an excel sheet and I want to put it in a plain .txt file structured and comma delimited like an CSV format style. Here's the data:

dn: uid=7097202

carLicense: 113363427

cn: Jean Arnofski

title: LBM356226

st: 16777212

- Next block separated by a blank row/line *

dn: uid=8178194

carLicense: 154052876

cn: Marie Gaulimerg

title: LBM356227

st: 16777219

etc...

The code I am using is this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LDIFParaCSV()
  Dim i, x, intHandle As Integer
  Dim lngNrLinhs As Long
  Dim rgnAlcance As Range
  Dim objFolhaExcel As Worksheet
  Dim strFich, strPChar As String
  Dim arrItemsSep

  Const cntEscrvFich = "csv_ldif.txt"

  intHandle = FreeFile
  Range("A2").Select

  Set objFolhaExcel = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set rgnAlcance = objFolhaExcel.UsedRange

  lngNrLinhs = rgnAlcance.Rows.Count + rgnAlcance.Row

  strFich = "d:\" & cntEscrvFich
  Open strFich For Output Access Write As #intHandle

  For i = 2 To lngNrLinhs + 1
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
       arrItemsSep = Split(Cells(i, 1), ":")
       Print #intHandle, arrItemsSep(1)
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
  Next

  Close #intHandle
End Sub
```

What I am trying to achieve is to put each block of data horizontally in the txt file in a single line (ex: uid=7097202, 113363427, Jean Arnofski, LBM356226, 16777212) and then the next block in the same manner in the next paragraph and so on, so on...

I am having great difficulty in achieving this... sorry, not so much of a programmer I think.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just added some lines to your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LDIFParaCSV()
  Dim i, x, intHandle As Integer
  Dim lngNrLinhs As Long
  Dim rgnAlcance As Range
  Dim objFolhaExcel As Worksheet
  Dim strFich, strPChar As String
  Dim arrItemsSep
  Dim printStr As String

    Const csvSeperator = ","
    Const cntEscrvFich = "csv_ldif.txt"

    printStr = ""

    intHandle = FreeFile
    Range("A2").Select

    Set objFolhaExcel = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    Set rgnAlcance = objFolhaExcel.UsedRange

    lngNrLinhs = rgnAlcance.Rows.Count + rgnAlcance.Row

    strFich = "D:\" & cntEscrvFich
    Open strFich For Output Access Write As #intHandle

    For i = 2 To lngNrLinhs + 1
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
            arrItemsSep = Split(Cells(i, 1), ":")
            'collect string elements
            printStr = printStr & arrItemsSep(1) & csvSeperator
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Else
            If printStr <> "" Then                           ' empty lines at end of range?
                printStr = Left(printStr, Len(printStr) - 2) ' remove trailing seperator
                Print #intHandle, Trim(printStr)             ' trim necessary?
                printStr = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next

  Close #intHandle
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much simple-solution! I've modified the code to suit my needs but the core code was very useful. Now I can manage what I wanted. Thank you!